# MongoDb + Laravel Passport problems install

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-passport

I have installed MongoDb and I can create tables using both migrations and seeder.

My problems are:

1. When I put the command `php artisan migrate`, the flow not registered the name of the table into migrations table, in this way the console show me this error:

> [MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException]     a collection
>   'victest.users' already exists

Where can I fix it?

2. The command `php artisan migrate` to create all tables of passport or others tables in migrations is not functional. Can I change this in the entire project?

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

to

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Model;
```

Now I have those problems, if someone had problems con mongodb and laravel passport please share you knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed again laravel 5.3 and my problems with migrate were solutioned
thanks